# How to skip values in a slice if it matches the condition first time

Tags: string, go, slice

How to skip the value in slice if the condition is matched once.

```
func main() {

    cloud := []string{"moon", "earth", "moon-light"}

    for _, value := range cloud {

        if strings.Contains(value, "mo") {
            fmt.Println("print1")
        } else if strings.Contains(value, "ear") {
            fmt.Println("print2")
        }
    }
}
```

Output :
print1
print2
print1

Expected Output :
print1
print2

gracias!

Comment: It's not clear what you want to skip. If the last `if` condition is true, you want to skip _further_ elements? If so, use a `break`.

Comment: Not exactly sure what you are looking to achieve but if you just want the first condition to only be true once then you can use a boolean flag initialised to  `moHappened := false` to mark when this has happened, and just add that boolean flag on your IF statement in conjunction with what you already have i.e. 
`if strings.Contains(value, "mo") && !moHappened { 
fmt.Println("print1") moHappened = true }`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a map to know if a certain condition has happened or not.
It is better than using variables because it allows you to track lots of conditions without any mess. here is an example of what you want:

```
cloud := []string{"moon", "earth", "moon-light"}
var conditionTracker = make(map[string]bool)

for _, value := range cloud {

    if _, ok := conditionTracker["first_condition"]; !ok && strings.Contains(value, "mo") {
        conditionTracker["first_condition"] = true
        fmt.Println("print1")
    } else if _, ok := conditionTracker["second_condition"]; !ok && strings.Contains(value, "ear") {
        conditionTracker["second_condition"] = true
        fmt.Println("print2")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "strings"
)

func main() {
    cloud := []string{"moon", "earth", "moon-light"}

    print1Flag := false
    print2Flag := false

    for _, value := range cloud {
        if strings.Contains(value, "mo") && !print1Flag {
            fmt.Println("print1")
            print1Flag = true
        } else if strings.Contains(value, "ear") && !print2Flag {
            fmt.Println("print2")
            print2Flag = true
        }
    }
}
```

The code checks the flag variables `print1Flag` and `print2Flag` to ensure that each condition is printed only once. The output will be:

```
print1
print2
```

Answer (score 0):

Other answers provide the basic mechanism(s) for your specific example, a solution for the general case could use a map containing a key that identifies the pattern to be matched, and the value for each key being the required result/output.

Once you have matched a key, delete it from the map so that it will not be matched a second time:

```golang
    cloud := []string{"moon", "earth", "moon-light"}
    match := map[string]string{
        "mo": "print1",
        "ear": "print2",
    }

    for _, value := range cloud {
        for k, v := range match {
            if strings.Contains(value, k) {
                fmt.Println(v)
                delete(find, k)
            }
        }
    }
```

This is perhaps less efficient (for larger slices and/or maps at least) since it involves two range loops, but if efficiency/scalability is of less concern than re-usability, this has the benefit of being able to be used for any one-time matches you may wish to perform by putting the code in a function:

```golang
func find(s []string, m map[string]string) (result []string) {
    for _, c := range s {
        for k, v := range m {
            if strings.Contains(c, k) {
                result = append(result, v)
                delete(m, k)
            }
        }
    }
    return result
}

func main() {
    cloud := []string{"moon", "earth", "moon-light"}
    match := map[string]string{"mo": "print1", "ear": "print2"}

    for _, r := range find(cloud, match) {
        fmt.Println(r)
    }
}
```

[Playground here](https://go.dev/play/p/R1Q4cHl-M1m).

(I'm not sure that 'find' is the best name for such a function as this is more of a transformation than a lookup; a better name in your specific use case I leave up to you :) )

With a small modification, the `find` function could become a filter, returning those entries in the slice that satisfy the match map (which no longer needs to be a map and can be a simple slice of substring matches).  So, if you have some processing to perform on the matching entries, not just transforming them/outputting some string, you would first filter then iterate over the returned slice:

```golang
func filter(s []string, m []string) (result []string) {
    for _, c := range s {
        for i, v := range m {
            if strings.Contains(c, v) {
                result = append(result, c)
                m = append(m[:i], m[i+1:]...)
            }
        }
    }
    return result
}

func main() {
    cloud := []string{"moon", "earth", "moon-light"}
    match := []string{"mo", "ear"}

    for _, r := range filter(cloud, match) {
        fmt.Println(r)
    }
}
```

Note that deleting items from a slice is a bit more cumbersome than deleting items from a map.

[Playground here.](https://go.dev/play/p/iJQYEK8zDWA)